# Expanding"clickable" area for custom icons using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have a searchable Leaflet map. The green icons represent all of the existing data and when you search for an address it shows a blue pushpin icon.

I would expect to be able to click anywhere on my custom (blue pushpin) icon and get a popup as a result. But nothing happens when I click on it.

[image]

I have to click on a very specific spot in order to get the popup to activate. I can tell it's the right spot because my hover text (on the bottom left) changes. I want to make it so that the results pop up if I click anywhere on the custom icon (or even the original green icon).

[image]

I'm using [a template](https://github.com/datamade/searchable-map-template-csv), so I'm not completely sure which part of the code controls the hover actions or the "clickable" area, but I'm guessing it's this...?

```
 var hover_template;
      $.get( "./templates/hover.ejs", function( template ) {
        hover_template = template;
      });
      SearchableMapLib.info.update = function (props) {
        if (props) {
          this._div.innerHTML = ejs.render(hover_template, {obj: props});
        }
        else {
          this._div.innerHTML = 'Hover over a ' + SearchableMapLib.recordName;
        }
      };

      SearchableMapLib.info.clear = function(){
        this._div.innerHTML = 'Hover over a ' + SearchableMapLib.recordName;
      };
```